# Removing hash using vue-router without reloading while in history mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This is not a repeat of the questions answering to just put the router in history mode.

I am using history mode. I have a legacy url https://somedomain.com/#/thankyou coming in from another app and I am trying to redirect to just https://somedomain.com/thankyou. I don’t want to change the location but instead use the vue-router. I have tried the following to no avail:

```
if (/#\/thankyou/.test(location.href)) {
  next({path:'/thankyou', replace:true, hash:''});
}
```

The result of this technique is that the page just reroutes to the same /#/thankyou.

Comment: wha's wrong with using `history` mode? Couldn't understand what you're looking for?

Comment: @Naren I am using history mode but I have an outside legacy path with the hash in it coming in to the app.

Comment: It seems like even though it is in history mode, it is trying unsuccessfully to respect the hash type navigation.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for it?

Comment: @Naren here is some code for you to look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1zjoqk?file=index.js